# Has $\mathrm{dx}$ notation usage question been asked already?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've browsed [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation), two introductory calculus textbooks, and then this site for questions. I am looking for a formal explanation on why it's valid to use the same differential notation such as $\mathrm{dx}$ in both differentiation ($\frac{d}{\mathrm{dx}}$ ) and integration ($\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{dx}$). Something like a proof, yet could be explained to Calculus I, II students.

I just want to make sure there isn't a question on this already before asking.

Comment: A perusal of the [questions tagged both (calculus) and (notation)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus+notation) brought the following two questions to my attention: [What does $dx$ mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/143222/8348), and [Usage of dx in Integrals](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1068/8348).  I don't know if either would satisfy you.

Comment: Why is  it valid to use the same symbol $\partial$ for partial derivatives and for the boundary of a set? Why  it valid to use $\times $ for multiplication of numbers and for  Cartesian product of sets? Because this is what people decided to do, that's why. Mathematical *claims* need proofs, not mathematical notation... Derivatives can be (and often are) written as $\dot{u}$ instead of $du/dt$. Integrals can be (and often are) written as $\int_a^b f$ instead of $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: 98130, that doesn't answer the (meta-)question.